# loop counting to 100 and back to 0 and up to 100 again and so on

Tags: javascript, loops, count

I must admit, I am not a mathematical expert, thats why I cant solve the following problem to my satisfaction.

I have a number, say i=0. I have a function that increases i on each call by 1 and then calls itself again, increasing i another time and another and another ... When reached 100 I want it to count backwards to 0 and then up again, kind of like an endles loop with i going up and down like an elevator. Whats an elegant solution for that?

My solution so far:

```
var countingUp = true;
var i = 0;

function count() {
if(i < 100 && countingUp) {i+=1}
if(i > 1 && !countingUp) {i-=1}

if(i===100) {countingUp=false;}
if(i===1) {countingUp=true;}

count()
}
count()
```

I am looking for something shorter.

Comment: Should there (I hope) be some delay between counts? Otherwise your environment will just lock up.

Comment: yes, dont try this code, its only for showing the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks ok to me, but will probably sell your dog into slavery and steal your beer:

```
var direction = 1;
var i = 0;

function count() {
   i += direction;
   direction *= (((i % 100) == 0) ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: looks tight, what does i % 100 do?

Comment: Divide by 100 and return the remainder.

Comment: running this code yields "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" one bracket to much ... direction *= ((i % 100 == 0) ? -1 : 1)

Answer (score 4):

The expression `abs((i % 200) - 100)` makes the sawtooth pattern that you want as i increases.

So then something like this:

```
var i = 100;
while (1) {
    var j = Math.abs((i % 200) - 100);
    // Use j
    // ...
    i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have a variable which will add or lower the amount if it's positive or negative. So you'll just have to change the variable sign.

```
var countingUp = 1;
var i = 0;

function count() {

    i += (1 * countingUp);

    if (i == 100 || i == 0)
    {
        countingUp *= -1;
    }
}
```

[fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/D3mQ9/)

To avoid having infinite recursion, just use a setInterval().

```
window.setInterval( count, 1 );
```

Comment: Infinite recursion... While loops... same thing for me (OK, not the same thing since JS runtimes don't support tail recursion :( )

Comment: @missingno just use setInterval and avoid calling the same function inside the same function... check my edited fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
function createCounter(min,max) {
    var dir = -1, val = min;
    return function() { return val += ((val >= max || val <= min) ? dir=-dir : dir); }
}
```

and then to use it

```
var counter = createCounter(0,5);
counter(); // 1
counter(); // 2
counter(); // 3
counter(); // 4
counter(); // 5
counter(); // 4
counter(); // 3
counter(); // 2
counter(); // 1
counter(); // 0
counter(); // 1
counter(); // 2
```